# How to set event that triggered when input:number element changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have this input number:

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-2" id="txtMonth" ng-model="month" min="1" max="12"/>
```

when value changed I need to file js function.how to set event that fired on event change?

Comment: you can use ngChange directive https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Comment: use ng-change="myFunction()" on element and define your myFunction() on your controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` directive to fire whatever the function you want .

```
<input type="number"  ng-model-options='{ debounce: 1000 }' ng-change='fireFunction()' />
```

In most cases you don't want to fire the function immediately. `ng-model-options='{debounce : Number}'` lets you wait before firing the handler.

About `debounce` : It just doesn't update the model at once but adds a delay of the value you specify. as debounce option

Answer (score 0):

Html:
`<input type="number" class="form-control input-sm col-xs-2" id="txtMonth" ng-model="month" ng-change="change()" min="1" max="12"/>`

Javascript :

```
angular.module('yourapp', [])
.controller('yourcontroller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.change = function() {
    /*..... Do Something Here  */
  };
}]);
```

Please Try This and let me know if your problem is solved.